# Insert excel file into a temp table SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-update

What I am trying to do is have an SSIS package that will import an excel file then do a SQL update on the records in that excel file.
Any tutorial would be great

Comment: Just to confirm, you are trying to import data into Excel?  From what database?  SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I would like to import data into a temp table from an excel file.

Comment: And then you want to use SQL to update the excel? or the db?...I have an answer for you but need to be clear in exactly what you want.

Comment: I am trying to update the db

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your question.  Let me know if you have any further problems.  P.S. you are getting down votes bc you didn't attempt anything or at least didn't show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Data Flow`-->`Excel Source` -->  `OLE DB Command` (Write a sp to create stage table (can't insert into #tempTable from SSIS, insert into stage table, update table)

In the `OLE DB Command` transformation.  `EXEC storedProcedure`.  You want to create variables in the sp to be used for `INSERT`.  You want to map those the columns from your `Excel Source` to those variables to be inserted.

Sorry, I don't have access to SSIS right now so am unable to provide screen shots.

Comment: Sorry I got pulled away from this but now I can try this. Is there any chance you can walk me through this? What would the variables look like from the insert?

Comment: Ill have to do it in chat...respond back when on SO

Comment: Im on now. How do we chat?

Comment: I thought we could but can't.

Comment: 1) Create a data flow task by dragging and dropping onto control flow(this can be found in your tool box) 2)drill into data flow task 3) drag and drop Excel Source from tool box onto data flow work place...let me know when you do that

Comment: Drill into your Excel Source and connect to file you want-->Then, drag and drop OLE DB Command transformation (from tool box).  Connect the Excel Source to the OLE DB Command....let me know when you have that done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75760/discussion-between-jjohnson-and-jeff-orris).

Comment: Just to confirm the answer....cant insert into #tempTable from SSIS...had user create stage table that could reuse.